# Database directory will not get created until explicitly specified in LOCATION field in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I created a database with my preferred location (/user/hive/) using below query.

```
create database test
location "/user/hive/";
```

After creating the database, I checked in the location `/user/hive/` for `test.db` directory using the command `hadoop dfs -ls /user/hive`. It was not available.

later I created one more database with default location using below query.

```
create database test2;
```

For database test2, I can see `test2.db` directory under default warehouse directory `/user/hive/warehouse/`

`/user/hive/test.db` directory got created when I explicitly specified it in LOCATION filed as below.

```
create database test
location "/user/hive/test.db";
```

As I'm new to Hive, Can any please explain.

Why `test.db` directory dint got created for my first query where I specified the location field as `/user/hive/`?

How Hive will work when location field is specified?

**NOTE**:

I'm using cloudera quick-start VM

Hive Version: Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.13.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behavior from Hive

```
create database test location "/user/hive/";
```

by executing above statement means you are creating **test** database on pointing to **/user/hive** directory so that's the reason why hive haven't created test directory.

We need to explicitly mention directory name also where we need to point the database in hive i.e  `create database test location "/user/hive/test.db";` then only hive creates test db pointing to test.db directory.

In case of `create database test2;` statement means we are creating database without specifying the location so this directory created under default hive warehouse location with same name as db name.